# How do I get a collection object in pyarango?

Tags: python, arangodb, pyarango

I can get a database object with the code:

```
import pyArango.database as DAT
db = DAT.Database(connection, dbName)
```

and according to the documentation, I can get a collection with the code:

```
import pyArango.collection as COL
collection = COL.Collection(database, jsonData)
```

How do I format jsonData to return my collection? I could not find how to do this in the documentation. My collection has `name="testCollection"`

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I figured it out. Collections should be instantiated by the database object, which is instantiated by the connection object.

```
import pyArango.connection as CON
db = CON.Connection(username=<user>, password=<password>).databases[<DB name>]
collection = db.collections['testCollection']
```

This works as intended, and returns:

```
ArangoDB collection name: testCollection, id: 14217, type: document, status: loaded
```